# Microsoft Excel: Using Lookup with another sheet

Tags: excel, formula

At work I have a list of products with a unique product code and the manufacturers name.

In a separate document I have a list of products we have in the shop floor, as well as our custom name for that product.

I want to populate the manufacturers spreadsheet with our product name by performing some form of lookup.

I've merged the two Excel spreadsheets to that I have one document, 2 sheets.

Product code format is `ABC1234`.

ManSheet

```
ID      | Manufacturer Name | Our Name
ABC1234 | Jolly             | Jilly
```

OurSheet

```
ID      | Our Name
ABC1234 | **=VLOOKUP(A1,'ManSheet'!A:A,2,FALSE)**
```

Could someone please help me with the formula.

Comment: I'm confused - what are you trying to do? Return the Manufacturer or Our name based on ID? Also, you are looking only in column A, and asking for the second column's result...Do you mean `...'Man Sheet'!A:B,2,FALSE)`?  (Also is it indeed "Man" or perhaps "Main"?)

Comment: Can you explain why there are asterisks in your `VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: I believe he meant ManSheet as manufacturers. I agree with the above comment, could you make it clearer as to which spreadsheet you want to carry out the lookup and what data you wish to check and bring back.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy - I bet that was for emphasis (**like bolding**) but OP didn't realize/know when you do that in code tags, it just shows the asterists (`**like this**`).

Answer (score 1):

**VLOOKUP**
First things first, you put the VLOOKUP on the sheet you wish to bring back the data to.

VLOOKUP syntax:

```
=VLOOKUP(Cell you wish to search, 
range of cells you wish want to check, 
Column on range with the value that you want to return, 
Exact/Approximate match)
```

So on your "ManSheet" add another column:

```
ID      | Manufacturer Name | Our Name | LookedUp Column
ABC1234 | Jolly             | Jilly    | =VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 1, FALSE)
```

So your lookup should be something along the lines of this, you can then drag this cell down to populate the rows below and do a mass vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4, ManSheet!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```